# Wso2 api manager, gateway doesn't invoke rest from the backend

Tags: wso2, invoke, gateway, api-manager

I'm new api manager, I installed it then I published a rest service but when I run it the gateway doesn't invoke the service

Please there is an issue in the config or what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error may be due to Access-Control-Allow-Header error, please check the browser developer-tool(F12) console for errors.

Set Access-Control-Allow-Headers to * In /wso2am-2.0.0/repository/conf/api-manager.xml and try.

thanks

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but the issue still exist, when I call it from the store or curl nothing happened

Comment: Hi @AliMejri what is error you see in the developer-tool console or when executing curl. please paste the error here. I may get some more idea about the issue. thanks.

Comment: Hi pravin sorry the problem had been solved cause your answer after the restart of apim thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try general troubleshooting techniques:

1. See if you can invoke some other REST service (not your backend).
2. If that succeeds, see if you can connect to your backend over HTTP (not HTTPS) - this can be a certificate issue of your gateway node not trusting the SLL certificate of the backend.
3. If that does not help, see if you can make things simpler: for example just have a GET /* and see if you can invoke that.
4. Logs can help to further look into the exact issues. You can also [enable call tracing with debug_ mediation sequences](http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/trace-api-calls-and-responses/).

And obviously if all things fail with your own API Manager deployment, there is always a hosted version - [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) - that is being run by WSO2 so things have been pre-configured by the company and maintained at the latest patch levels and best practices.